# Sqflite throws an error(MissingPluginException) only in web. flutter web

Tags: flutter

```
  Future<void> saveDB() async {
    DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper();

    var write = Write(
      id: stringToSha512(DateTime.now().toString()),
      title: "First",
      text: "First",
      createTime: DateTime.now().toString(),
      editTime: DateTime.now().toString(),
    );
    await dbHelper.insertWrite(write);

    print(await dbHelper.write());
  }
```

```
class DBHelper {
  var dbHelper;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (dbHelper != null) return dbHelper;
    dbHelper = openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'write.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        return db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE write(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, text TEXT, createTime TEXT, editTime TEXT)",
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );
    return dbHelper;
  }

  Future<void> insertWrite(Write write) async {
    final db = await database;
    await db.insert(
      tableName,
      write.toMap(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }
```

```
class Write {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String text;
  final String createTime;
  final String editTime;

  Write({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.text,
    this.createTime,
    this.editTime,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'text': text,
      'createTime': createTime,
      'editTime': editTime,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Write{id: $id, title: $title, text: $text, createTime: $createTime, editTime: $editTime}';
  }
}
```

sorry about the long codes..

Im getting this error : MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite) in both Chrome and Edge. but not in Pixel. So I guess It should be about flutter web.

How can I solve this? to make sure I checked flutter doctor and licenses. Also, I cleaned the project once and ran it. the result got no difference.

I set the void on "onPressed" of a button to test. Since I clicked it I got the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Sqflite plugin's readme page [sqfLite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) this package is not supported on flutter web.

**Refer bellow image:**
[image: here]

**Reason:**

SqfLite is a package that stores the database on the devices local storage, for web you don't have that functionality , so you can't use this package with Flutter web. That's all causing the error.

Comment: Many thanks.. I shouldve read the package page

Comment: Good to hear @revilbary  If this answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this comment in Github, it is now possible to use sqflite on web: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/212#issuecomment-1109461668

**Summary:**

Copy sqlite3.wasm to the web application folder `/web/sqlite3.wasm` (You can get the file from https://storage.googleapis.com/simon-public-euw3/assets/sqlite3.wasm)

Make sure to use sqlite_common_ffi and sqlite_common from here: https://github.com/muhleder/sqflite/tree/web/sqflite_common_ffi

The sample code mentioned in the answer should work

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi/sqflite_ffi.dart';

Future<Database> openWebDb() async {
  databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
  Database db = await openDatabase('/test/test.db');
  return db;
}
```

In my case, my pubspec.yaml ended as following to make it work (however I'm not sure if adding the overrides is the best approach but it was the only way that worked for me):

```
dependencies:
  sqflite:
  sqflite_common:
  sqflite_common_ffi:

dependency_overrides:
  sqflite_common:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/muhleder/sqflite.git
      ref: web
      path: sqflite_common
  sqflite_common_ffi:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/muhleder/sqflite.git
      ref: web
      path: sqflite_common_ffi
```